# Splitting a string on a number of whitespaces using Regex and VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a table in the following format:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4  col5  col6
test   300     25.5   14   345   11
test2           100   23   11    203
test3  31                  44    175
```

So even though the number of columns is set and columns are aligned, some columns can be blank. The space between columns is at least 2 whitespace characters. So I am using:

```
If Regex.Split(line, "[ ]{2,}").Length = 6 Then
  sw.WriteLine("col1: " & Regex.Split(line, "[ ]{2,}")(0))
  sw.WriteLine("col2: " & Regex.Split(line, "[ ]{2,}")(1))
  sw.WriteLine("col3: " & Regex.Split(line, "[ ]{2,}")(2))
  sw.WriteLine("col4: " & Regex.Split(line, "[ ]{2,}")(3))
  sw.WriteLine("col5: " & Regex.Split(line, "[ ]{2,}")(4))
  sw.WriteLine("col6: " & Regex.Split(line, "[ ]{2,}")(5))                          
End If
```

inside a loop that grabs each line and writes it to a stream writer.

It would work fine if some column values were not missing. In the example above the first line would run fine, but for lines two and 3, `Regex.Split(line, "[ ]{2,}").Length`  would return 5 and 4 respectively. Is there a workaround? I want `Regex.Split(line, "[ ]{2,}").Length`  to return 6 as the number of columns and fill the corresponding parts of the array with blanks.

Comment: Can you change the delimiter?

Comment: unfortunately not. I cannot change the input file format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly certain what your expected output is, although setting a maximum number for the amount of spaces to split by should work:

```
string[] s = Regex.Split(line, @"\s{2,6}");
```

**Code:**

```
    string line;
    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {

        // Console.WriteLine(line); // original output

        string[] s = Regex.Split(line, @"\s{2,6}");

        int i = 0;
        foreach (string word in s) {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine("col"+i+": " + word);
        }
    }
```

**Example:**

**http://ideone.com/0lZLk1**

Comment: Thanks! I just replaced "[ ],{2,}" with "\s{4,8}" and it seems to work for me